# Can GEEs handle the Simpson's paradox?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm a somewhat seasoned user of mixed effects/multilevel models but I don't know much about Generalized Estimating Equations (GEEs). Over time, I've been seen many people claim that GEEs can be used to handle the same kind of correlated/clustered data that mixed effects models are often used for.

However, one thing that always puzzled me is: can GEEs handle the correlated data if the trend **across clusters** is opposite to the trend **within clusters**? I.e. the situation that is often cited as one of the examples of Simpson's paradox?

I've simulated some data like this in R:

```
set.seed(123456)
beta_s <- rnorm(10, 0, 0.5)
alpha_s <- rnorm(10, 0, 15)
x <- round(runif(100, 1, 10), 2)

df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:10, each = 10),
             alpha = 100, beta = -1.25, 
             alpha_s = rep(alpha_s, each = 10),
             beta_s = rep(beta_s, each = 10))

df <- transform(df, x = rnorm(100, 0.2 * alpha_s, 1))
df <- transform(df, y = alpha + alpha_s + (beta + beta_s) * x + rnorm(100))

ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = factor(id))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

When I model this data using a mixed effects model fitted with `cmdstanr`, I can recover the negative beta parameter very well. However, when I try fitting it with `geepack::geeglm(y ~ x, id = id, data = df)`, I get a strong **positive** estimate for the slope of x (that's also highly statistically significant!).

Am I perhaps specifying the model incorrectly or is GEE the wrong sort of tool for this job? Can we use GEEs to estimate within-cluster trends at all?

Answer (score 2):

The default in `geepack::geelm()` is to have an independence working correlation matrix. If you alter this, you obtain similar results, i.e., `geeglm(y ~ x, data = df, id = id, corstr = "ar1")`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the AR1 correlation structure was specific to autoregressive models. Could you please give me an intuition why the AR1 structure leads to within-cluster estimates?